# Rails: handling nullable attribute in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model that has a polymorphic association.

```
class User
  belongs_to :address, polymorphic: true, optional: true
end
```

I call `user.address.street` on many place of the code, when address is nil I have to use a default address, so I need to check if nil in many parts.

I'd like to find an alternative to prevent this check if nil

Comment: Use a helper method or a decorator.

Comment: Like @max said Decorate the object. Then you can create a `DefaultAddress` which acts like an `Address` as needed for display purposes.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a migration to set `street` as default value as below:

```
class ChangeStreetDefaultValue < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column(:table_name, :street, :text, default: DEFAULT_STREET)
    ModelName.where(street: nil).update_all(street: DEFAULT_STREET) 
  end
end
```

or
you can run the migration to update the default street and run the script on the console separately to update existing records.